# jQuery logical operators for flow control instead of using if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I can't get the succinct flow control syntax to work with jQuery. The following throws an error:

```
$(this).hasClass('expanded') && return
```

Whereas this longer version works fine:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) { return}
```

Any ideas why the first one is throwing an error?

Comment: Those two lines are very different, and personally I've never seen the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could save tipying the `{}`:

```
if($(this).hasClass('expanded')) return;
```

Comment: thanks that saved a bit of typing, actually it can be made even shorter by removing the semi colon at the end
 if($(this).hasClass('expanded')) return

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use the logical AND with the `return` statement like this. However, I can't see a reason why you would do it like that. You could just return the boolean result directly from a function

```
return $(this).hasClass('expanded');
```

Comment: I'm not interested in returning the result I just want the rest of the code in the block not to execute if the condition is true. I tried this and it doesn't work for me but thanks for your answer anyway, I guess I can't use this syntax with return as you say

Comment: @techjacker: well, either your example is badly choosen or I don't get it. The thing is, every function in ECMAscript returns a value. If not specified, it returns the `undefined` value. So, Checking for a boolean expresion to either call `return` or not, does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Each part of the boolean logical operator must evaluate to something. return can't do that.

I actually hadn't thought of using it like that before, I would have thought off the top of my head that it would work too.